# How can I add a .submitLabel() to a SwiftUI TextField() with a numberPad

Tags: swiftui, textfield, uikeyboardtype

Is it possible to add a .submitLable() to a TextField that has the keyboard type .numberPad. All the information I can find is that it's not possible but that information is 2 years old. So I hope that it might have changed.

I have the following code but the submit label doesn't appear on the keyboard when I actually run the app.

```
TextField("placeholder", text: $placeholder)
    .submitLabel(.next)
    .keyboardType(.numberPad)
```

Is there a way to add a submit label or something of similar functionality to a TextField with a keyboard type of numberPad in SwiftUI or is it just not possible with SwiftUI currently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `.submitLabel()` modifies the "return" key display/behavior in the keyboard, but with `.numberPad` there is no such key to modify. (You can see this behavior by experimenting with different values for `.submitLabel()` using the default keyboard type)

It is possible to add an `inputAccessoryView` to a `UITextField` with a system defined and pre-localized `.done` button. (Or `.next`, or several others) It is somewhat cumbersome, though.

For example, using a generic type `Value` that conforms to `BinaryInteger`:

```
struct NumberTextField<Value: BinaryInteger>: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var value: Value
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.keyboardType = .numberPad
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        textField.inputAccessoryView = createToolbar()
        return textField
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = "\(value)"
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(value: $value)
    }
    
    private func createToolbar() -> UIToolbar {
        // if you want behavior other than "dismiss", put it in action:
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(UIApplication.dismissKeyboard))
        
        let spacer = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        
        let toolbar = UIToolbar()
        toolbar.sizeToFit()
        toolbar.items = [spacer, doneButton]

        // you may want to check the locale for right-to-left orientation,
        // if it doesn't automatically re-orient the sequence of items.

        return toolbar
    }

    // I don't recall where I got this code, its purpose is mostly to
    // filter out non-numeric values from the input, it may be suboptimal
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        var value: Binding<Value>
        
        init(value: Binding<Value>) {
            self.value = value
        }
        
        func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
            let allowedCharacters = CharacterSet.decimalDigits
            let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)
            return allowedCharacters.isSuperset(of: characterSet)
        }
        
        func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
            // if you use a different protocol than BinaryInteger
            // you will most likely have to change this behavior
            guard let text = textField.text else { return }
            guard let integer = Int(text) else { return }
            value.wrappedValue = Value(integer)
        }
    }
}
```

Here, `UIApplication.dismissKeyboard` is an extension on `UIApplication` like this, which essentially tells whatever currently has focus (to show the keyboard) to give it up:

```
extension UIApplication {
    @objc
    func dismissKeyboard() {
        sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    }
}
```

I have used this with Swift 5.5 and a target of iOS 16.x. It should work with some prior versions of Swift / iOS, but I have not tested it with anything else.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. This far out I didn't even expect a reply anymore. Which just makes me even more thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my method:

1. Use enum for FocusState.
2. Add focused value to each textfield.
3. Create a toolbaritem button on the keyboard with action.
4. Check the current focused value and pass it into a function.
5. Assign the next focused value into current focusState.

   ```
   enum FocusText {
       case apple, orange
   }
   @State private var apple: String = ""
   @State private var orange: String = ""
   @FocusState private var focusField: FocusText?

   TextField("Type here", value: $apple)
      .focused($focusField, equals:.apple)
      .keyboardType(.decimalPad)

   TextField("Type here", value: $orange)
      .focused($focusField, equals:.orange)
      .keyboardType(.decimalPad)

   ToolbarItem(placement: .keyboard) {

   Button("Next")
   {  UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder),to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)                                

   if focusField == .apple {
   focusField = .orange
     }
   }
   ```

If you want it to go to the next column instead of a dedicated one:

1. Make FocusText iterable
2. Read the currentValue of focusedState
3. pass it into a func to get the next case
4. assign it to current focusedState
   (Make sure the cases are in correct order)

   ```
    enum FocusText: CaseIterable {
    case apple, orange
    }

    Button("Next")
        { UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder),to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)                                

    var currentField = focusField.unsafelyUnwrapped
    focusField = nextCase(of: currentField)
    }

    func nextCase(of focusField: FocusText) -> FocusText {
    let allCases = FocusText.allCases
    let currentIndex = allCases.firstIndex(of: focusField)!
    let nextIndex = allCases.index(after: currentIndex)
    return allCases[nextIndex % allCases.count] 
    }
   ```